# Unable to assign a number from an array to a variable in a batch file

Tags: arrays, batch-file, global-variables

My batch file is trying to access random numbers stored in an simple list array by assigning the random numbers in the array to a variable. The batch file will then loop through to the next number.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
:loop
set /a num=%random% %% 135 + 1
if "!numlist!" == "" (
    set numlist=!num!
    set /a count+=1
) else (
    for %%i in (!numlist!) do (
        if !num! == %%i (
            goto loop
        )
        if !num! == %%i+1 (
            goto loop
        )
        if !num! == %%i-1 (
            goto loop
        )
    )
    set numlist=!numlist! !num!
    set /a count+=1
)
if !count! lss 135 (
    goto loop
)
echo !numlist!

set /a i=0
for %%n in (!numlist!) do (
    set arr[!i!]=%%n
    set /a i+=1
)
rem Display the array elements
for /l %%i in (0,1,135) do (
echo !arr[%%i]!

)

rem Set the path to the folder containing the files to be renamed
set folderPath="D:\Path\To\Files"

rem Rename up to 135 files in the specified folder using the random numbers from the array
set /a g=0
for %%f in ("%folderPath%\*.*") do (
    if !g! geq 135 goto endloop
rem echo var g is !g!
    set "num=!arr[!g!]!"
rem echo var num is !num!
    ren "%%f" "!num! - %%~nxf"
    set /a g+=1
    set /a i+=1
)
:endloop
endlocal
```

As only an occasional coder I took a long time to write this script. It is designed to add a random number to the filename of a folder containing 135 files (this will be modified to add a filenum variable for use on any folder). The numbers will not be duplicated or consecutive.

It works as expected until the set "num=!arr[!g!]!" line. The value of variable "num" is not set to the random number from the array but is set to "g" in every iteration of the loop giving the output "g - [file_name]. extension" and not "[random_number] *-* [file_name].extension".

I have spent hours googling and experimenting but I can't find a solution. I have a feeling it may be something obvious to a more experienced coder. I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: delayed variables cannot be nested within each other.  the interpreter sees: `!arr[!g!]!` as two variables: `!arr[!` and `!]!` with the letter g in between, and as they are undefined, all you get is `g`. If you need to expand a delayed variable using another delayed variable while in a code block, use: `For /f "delims=" %%G in ("!g!")Do Set "num=!arr[%%G]!"`

Answer (score 0):

This should set you in the right direction

**It does not completely cure your problem**

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET maxc=0

:again
set /a count=0
SET "numlist="
:loop
set /a num=%random% %% 135 + 1
IF "%numlist%" neq "" (
 for %%i in (%numlist%) do (
  if %num% == %%i (
     goto loop
  )
  SET /a num+=1
  if !num! == %%i (
     goto again
  )
  SET /a num-=2
  if !num! == %%i (
     goto again
  )
  SET /a num+=1
 )
)
set numlist=%numlist% %num%
set /a count+=1
IF %count% gtr %maxc% (
 ECHO %count% %TIME%
 SET /a maxc=count
)
if %count% lss 29 (
    goto loop
)
echo %numlist%

set /a i=0
for %%n in (%numlist%) do (
    set arr[!i!]=%%n
    set /a i+=1
)
rem Display the array elements
for /l %%i in (0,1,28) do (
echo !arr[%%i]!

)
ECHO %time%

rem Set the path to the folder containing the files to be renamed
set folderPath="D:\Path\To\Files"

rem Rename up to 11 files in the specified folder using the random numbers from the array
set /a g=0
for %%f in ("%folderPath%\*.*") do (
    if !g! geq 29 goto endloop
rem echo var g is !g!
    set "num=%arr[!g!]%"
rem echo var num is !num!
ECHO    ren "%%f" "!num! - %%~nxf"
    set /a g+=1
    set /a i+=1
)
:endloop

GOTO :EOF
```

We have **!madness**. `%var%`==`!var!` EXCEPT within a loop, where `%var%` is the value of `var` **before the loop started to be executed** and `!var!` the value **as it may have changed in the loop.**

So - implicitly, `!var!` is the value as the loop changes `var` and `%var%` is the value otherwise.

`maxc` is the maximum count of `numlist` entries found.

In your code, for the `%%i` loop, `num` is not changed within the loop, and `numlist` is not used after it has been changed, so `%var%` is the correct syntax.

```
if %num% == %%i+1
```

does not evaluate `%%i+1`, so the comparison is performed as (eg) `37 == 36+1` not `37 == 37` and will thus *always* be FALSE. Hence, your pre/succeeding number detection will fail.

I have replaced that method with one that demonstrates the use of `%var%` against `!var!`. Given that `num` is `37` for instance, then test `37` against `%%i`, add 1 to `num` and test `38` against `%%i`, subtract 2 and test `36` against `%%i`, and finally add 1 again to restore the original `num`.

The first time around, `numlist` will be empty, so all of this testing is bypassed and `num` appended to `numlist`. Once the first number has been added to `numlist`, that testing will be executed.

I added a little code to demonstrate what's happening with your next problem. Test `count` to see whether it's reached a new maximum. If it has, record the new maximum found in `maxc` and report the count and time.

You will find that the routine will become slower and slower in reporting the count and time. This is because you are testing **EACH** number in `numlist` to `num`, `num+1` and `num-1` when you should be testing only the *last* number chosen against `num`.

Ah! - But I've changed the `+/-1` to goto `again`, not `loop`. True, but suppose your only numbers left are *all* one different from (any number in `numlist`). We can never choose a valid number, so we'll get an infinite loop.

Even with the correction made to test only the *last* number chosen against `num`, suppose we have only `15,16` unchosen (not in `numlist`). We again have an infinite-loop situation, as we can only choose successive numbers.

So - I changed the limit to `29` numbers (1..135) as that took <2 mins on my machine. Setting it higher would produce an infinite loop or take an unacceptable time.

Note that having chosen the numbers in `numlist`, you are entering them into a 0-based array, so `28` is used here.

Finally, we arrive at the renaming loop. I haven't run this, just fixed it in theory.

note that `g` and `num` are being changed within the loop, but `arr*` is not. Your code `set "num=!arr[!g!]!"` would set `num` to (the current value of `arr[`)+g+(the current value of `]`) which most likely evaluates to `g`.

By `echo`ing the `ren` command, no harm is done if the `ren` is not as expected.

And there's no apparent reason for incrementing `i`.

Comment: This command don't works: `set "num=%arr[!g!]%"`

Comment: @Aacini : QUite so. Should be `CALL set "num=%%arr[!g!]%%"`

Comment: My problem is now solved and given the contributions from the above expert coders some large gaps in my knowledge have been filled. My modified script now runs really well and I can now move on to the next stage of my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... Let's analyze your code a little before trying to fix the problem...

In your code you first generate 135 random numbers that are *not* consecutive, right?

Well, the first `if` just works *one time* when `numlist` is empty. After that, the rest of times the `else` part is executed... This seems a waste of code, isn't it? Why not just initialize the list with *the first number* the first time? In this way you can entirely eliminate the (useless) `if`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A numlist=%random% %% 300 + 1, count=1

:loop
   set /A num=%random% %% 300+1, numP1=num+1, numM1=num-1
```

After that, you process *all `numlist` elements* one by one in order to compare each element vs `num` (and `numP1` and `numM1`). You should note that `numlist` is a *string* (not an array), so you can easily process the whole string via `!numlist:%num%=!` syntax: if the result is *different than before*, then `%num%` *is contained* in the string!  **`;)`**

```
   if "!numlist:%num%=!" neq "%numlist%" goto loop
   if "!numlist:%numP1%=!" neq "%numlist%" goto loop
   if "!numlist:%numM1%=!" neq "%numlist%" goto loop

   set "numlist=%numlist% %num%"
   set /A count+=1
if %count% lss 135 goto loop
echo %numlist%

rem Copy "numlist" items into "arr" array
set "i=0"
for %%n in (%numlist%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "arr[!i!]=%%n"
)

rem Display the array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,135) do echo !arr[%%i]!
```

Note that:

- There is no way to generate 135 *non consecutive* numbers in the range 1..135. You need the double range at least! As the range is greater, the process will take less time. I used `300`.
- Parts in `if` command are enclosed in quotes in order to make they more readable.
- The inclusion of quotes in `set "var=value"` command is a good practice that eliminate any unnoted blank space at end of the value.
- I used to start array elements at 1 (instead of common C's 0), this aids to avoid subtle errors. For example, in your code the `for /l %%i in (0,1,135) do` is wrong: it should be (0,1,134)

The second part is almost correct excepting this line: `set "num=!arr[!g!]!"`. You could use `call set "num=%%arr[!g!]%%"` or `for %%g in (!g!) do set "num=!arr[%%g]!"` as described with detail at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/778560)